# WP_QUERY with group by with custom fields

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

I need to use group by in my posts with a custom field "eventMonth" that will have values like "April-2019" - "June-2019"..

(I never used the wp_query with a meta_query data so...).
I've the next query and code in my category fieldfunction

```
query_group_by_filter($groupby){
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->postmeta . ".meta_value='eventMonth'";
 }:

$query = array(
    "category_name"=>"events",
    "posts_per_page"=>-1,
    "order"=>"ASC",
    "meta_query"=>array(
        'relation'=>"OR",
        array(
            'key'=>"eventMonth",
            'compare'=> "="
        )
    ),
    'meta_key'=>"eventMonth"
);

add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'query_group_by_filter' );
```

If I make the loop, I can see only 1 result when I've four posts with this custom field.

How could I do that group by?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, and what are the values of `eventMonth` for those 4 posts?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż 2 have "April-2019" and others have "June-2019" and "May-2019"...I supose that this query should give this 4 post but applying the group by, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Revised answer)*

So after discussing via the comments, what you really need is a custom `ORDER BY` clause, which in WordPress post queries (`WP_Query`), you can set the clause via the `posts_orderby` [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/) just like you can set custom `GROUP BY` clause via the `posts_groupby` [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_groupby/).

> The order that I need is June - 2019 | May - 2019 | April - 2019 |
>   April - 2019

If the value of the meta `eventMonth` is always in this format: `{month name} - {4-digit year}` such as `June - 2019` — note the dash/hypen which shouldn't be "–" or any other special characters, then the following `ORDER BY` clause can sort the posts in the order specified above: (the WordPress table prefix is assumed as being `wp_` and this example sorts in descending order)

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( REPLACE( wp_postmeta.meta_value, '-', '1,' ), '%M %e, %Y' ) DESC
```

And the PHP code:

1. Modify the `ORDER BY` clause:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'query_order_by_filter', 10, 2 );
   function query_order_by_filter( $orderby, $query ) {
       // Modify only if and when applicable.
       if ( 'eventMonth_date' === $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) {
           global $wpdb;
           $order = $query->get( 'order' );
           return "STR_TO_DATE( REPLACE( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value, '-', '1,' ), '%M %e, %Y' ) $order";
       }

       return $orderby;
   }
   ```
2. When making your post/`WP_Query` queries, set the `orderby` parameter to `eventMonth_date`:

   ```php
   $args = array(
       'meta_key' => 'eventMonth',
       'orderby'  => 'eventMonth_date',
       'order'    => 'DESC',
       // ... other args.
   );
   $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   ```

   PS: If you use `get_posts()` instead of `new WP_Query()`, make sure to set `suppress_filters` to `false`.

Comment: If I change that, I've more results but I can see only 1 (not 2) who share the same value to "eventMont" (I've two with "April-2019" and I can see only one)

Comment: Actually, is it necessary to use the `GROUP BY` clause to achieve what you need? How about using PHP to group the returned posts (by the meta value)?

Comment: Or you could use the `ORDER BY` clause to sort the posts by the meta value. Have you tried `'orderby' => 'meta_value'`? Does it help in what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh thanks! That is just I need but I need the natural order like: 
June-2019 | April-2019 | April-2019 | May-2019.I put the order=>ASC, order=>DESC but I don't have the correct result.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "natural order"? By the post date?

Comment: The order that I need is June - 2019 | May - 2019 | April - 2019 | April - 2019 @sallycj

Comment: The "correct" order for this example is June - 2019 | May - 2019 | April - 2019 | April - 2019 but this values are examples (I can have June - 2020 | May - 2018 | May - 2018...diferents months and years)

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know.

Comment: Yes!!! It works!! Thanks! @Sally CJ
Just other question...Is possible to applay that `query` if the language change? This works perfectly in English but if the date (January , May...etc...) was wrote in spanish (Junio, Mayo...)?

Comment: Hey @Marcos. Sorry for the late reply. Did you manage to find a solution for localized months? If not and you still need help with that, do let me know.